# Filtered Data Not Getting Called Correctly

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have an app that allows the user to assign expenses to selected categories. The Setup Categories view contains two boxes Available Categories and Current Categories. Tapping on a category in the Available Categories box moves it to the Current Categories box. The opposite is also true: tapping on a category in the Current Categories box moves it to the Available Categories box. A category in the Current Category box may not be moved to the Available box if the category has a nonzero balance.

The problem that I see is the ability to remove a category from the Current Categories box after a transaction has just been recorded. The transaction can be confirmed by looking at the history view, category totals view, and debug code in the Setup Categories view. But upon going to the Category Update view, I can now delete the category. If I don't move the category out of the Current Categories box and restart the app, then the category is prevented from being moved out.

The category data is filtered to prevent gaps from appearing in the category listings. I believe this data is not getting updated correctly. The method updateStatus is only called when the category structure is read. I would like to call this from Update Categories but it is not allowed because it is a view (Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'). **Any ideas on how to fix this?**

Note: I didn't include GetAvailableCats() since it is almost identical to GetCurrentCats() except that it uses filteredNotInUse.

```
// working categories
struct CatModel:  Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var catName: String     // category name
    var catTotal: Double    // category total
    var catBudget: Double   // category budget
    var catPix: String      // sf symbol
    var catShow: Bool       // true: in Use, false: available
}

class Categories: ObservableObject {
    @Published var filteredInUse: [CatModel] = []
    @Published var filteredNotInUse: [CatModel] = []

    @Published var catItem: [CatModel] {
        didSet {
           if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(catItem) {
               UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: StorageKeys.workCat.rawValue)
           }
        }
    }

    init() {

        if let catItem = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: StorageKeys.workCat.rawValue) {
            if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([CatModel].self, from: catItem) {
                self.catItem = decoded
                self.updateStatus()
                return
            }
        }

        catItem = []

        let item0 = CatModel(catName: "Category A", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "scribble", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item0)

        let item1 = CatModel(catName: "Category B", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "scribble", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item1)

        let item2 = CatModel(catName: "Category C", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "scribble", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item2)

        self.updateStatus()
   }

    func updateStatus() {
        filteredInUse = catItem.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return user.catShow == true
        })

        filteredNotInUse = catItem.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return user.catShow == false
        })
     }
   
    func addNewCatetory(catName: String) -> () {

        let item = CatModel(catName: catName, catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "person.2")
        catItem.append(item)
    }
```

```
struct ShowCategories: View {

    @State private var presentAlert = false
    @State private var presentDetail: String = ""

    var g: GeometryProxy

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Current Categories")
               

            ScrollView {
                GetCurrentCats(g: g, presentAlert: $presentAlert, presentDetail: $presentDetail)

            } .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.80, height: g.size.height * 0.35)
                .border(Color(.systemBlue), width: 4)

            Text("Available Categories")

            ScrollView {
                GetAvailableCats(g: g)

            } .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.80, height: g.size.height * 0.35).border(Color(.systemBlue), width: 4)

        }.alert(
            "Unable to remove category.", isPresented: $presentAlert,
            presenting: presentDetail
        ) { detail in

            Button("OK") {}
        } message: { detail in
            Text("\(presentDetail) category has a nonzero balance.")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Setup Categories", displayMode: .inline)
        
    }
}



struct GetCurrentCats: View {

    var g: GeometryProxy

    @State private var showStatus: Bool = false

    @Binding var presentAlert: Bool
    @Binding var presentDetail: String

    @EnvironmentObject var categories: Categories

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
          
            ForEach(categories.filteredInUse, id: \.id) { item in
                Button(action: {
                    if item.catTotal == 0.0 {
                            showStatus = false
                       
                    } else {
                        presentAlert = true
                        presentDetail = item.catName
                    }
                }){
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: item.catPix)
                            .resizable()
                         // .foregroundColor(Color(colors[index]))
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)

                        Text(item.catName)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                            .background(item.catTotal != 0.0 ? Color(.systemRed) : Color(.systemBlue))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `...I would like to call this from Update Categories but it is not allowed...`, where is, or where would you like to call Update Categories and `updateStatus()`. Where in your code (what line) do you get the `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'`.

Comment: I would like to call categories.UpdateStatus() in ShowCategories() before the two calls GetCurrentCats() and GetAvailableCats(). I have tried several locations in GetCurrentCats() and GetAvailableCats and in ShowCategories() without success. All producing the same error Type '()'cannot conform to 'View'. Of course I have @StateObject var categories = Categories() above the body.

Comment: In `ShowCategories`  you need to have `@EnvironmentObject var categories: Categories` 
just like you have in `GetCurrentCats`. Then use `.onAppear { categories.UpdateStatus() }`.